# Database - What is a good database design for a booking system?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have a school task where I have to build a booking system for meetings for a (fictional) company that has to fulfill the requirements in this pdf: http://docdro.id/FmHngHe (its better for you to read it then me trying to explain the details, all you have to read is part 2 and half of part 3. Its not that much :) )

The problem I am facing right now is to create a proper database design for this project. I have a vague idea of how the design should look like. I know for example (approximately) what entity types I should have for this project but I am struggling in trying to figure out how all the tables should be connected. What should the relationships be like and what extra relationship tables do I need.

This is what I got so far:
[image]

But it feels like I am missing a big part of the puzzle here. It feels incomplete. I feel like there should be a whole lot more relationship tables in the design but then I will end up with over 10 tables which feels like a bit much for such a small project or am I doing this completely wrong?

I would like this to be a very simple design. Am I overcomplicating this?

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: this is a good question but probably too broad and slightly off-topic for SO

Comment: Read up on [normalization forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: As said by tadman the normalization form is your best guide here. In your case, the position will be repeated for possibly every user. A company has a finite set of positions, isn't it? So perhaps a table `position` could be useful to avoid repeatitions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, first of all, write all the requirements in one table. 1 row is the flat structure of all the requirements. Then start breaking it one by one. That 1 table structure should be having all the required columns. Then follow **Normalization** concepts of breaking 1 single table into multiple tables.

Comment: I am new to databases and database design but as far as I have understood it, Normalization is just a way to optimize existing database designs. I am more wondering if anything is missing from my current database design or if I made any stupid decisions. It doesn't have to be perfect... just good enough.

Comment: @Schytheron I have given a general idea of how to do any RDBMS design. This is the process which one should be following. In this way, one won't feel like he is missing something.